# SQL: how to use loop in PIVOT

Tags: sql, pivot

My SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
    cmdoc.documentno 'DRG. NO.',
    cmdoc.subject 'TITLE',
    CAST(documentno AS VARCHAR(255)) AS docno, 
    CAST(cmrev.code AS VARCHAR(255)) AS code
FROM cmdocument cmdoc
INNER JOIN cmdocumentrevision cmrev
    ON cmdoc.cmdocument = cmrev.cmdocument
INNER JOIN cmdocumentdefn
    ON cmdoc.cmdocumentdefn = cmdocumentdefn.cmdocumentdefn
WHERE 
cmdocumentdefn.isrevisable = 1 
) x
PIVOT(COUNT(docno) FOR code IN([A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[F],[G])) pvt
```

I want to **loop** the line inside **IN**('/* here */').
If possible, I want the **start** and **end** to be an SQL like:

```
-- start
SELECT MIN(code) FROM table
-- end
SELECT MAX(code) FROM table
```

how can I do it?

Comment: You want to get a variable number of columns in your result? This is not possible in SQL. A table in a SQL database is defined by its columns. They are static. A SQL query, too, results in a table (albeit not one that gets stored in the database), so the query defines the table. And this definition is a fixed number of columns. The solution is simple: Don't try to get the data in a variable number of columns, but in a variable number of rows. Then, in your app or Website you read that data and display it to your likes (i.e. in a grid consisting of as many columns as you need for the data).

Comment: Yeah, it's also not possible I think. I just have to think simple with this. I just have to achieve this using my reporting tool which is Stimulsoft.